# convert html special character code in string coldfusion

Tags: html, coldfusion, special-characters

for the project we are working on there is a csv file that data is being pulled from then inserted into the database. unfortunately for some reason the data is formatted with html special character codes example `Dunkin&#39; Brands Group, Inc.` and even more unfortunate we have no control over the generated file. I am having a hard time finding a way to convert the character codes to html before inserting into the database using ColdFusion functions. any suggestions?

Comment: First, quantify "having a hard time", secondly... why do you think you need to convert anything here? `&#39;` - for example - is completely legit in HTML. Indeed it *is* a specifically HTML character encoding. What are you actually trying to achieve here?